# Activity with multiple tables in sql database crashes - Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-cursor

I want to create a shop for my app, and I´m stuck because I´m not able to save the data that I need to make the item´s shopping work in my sql database. I used three cursors, one for each table, but when I try to retrieve that data from the database, the app crashes and gives me these errors:

> 2021-09-02 17:57:00.195 27466-27466/? E/com.example.a1: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
> 2021-09-02 17:57:00.218 27466-27466/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "runtime.mmitest.isrunning"
> 2021-09-02 17:57:00.395 27466-27501/com.example.a14 E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@feea179
> 2021-09-02 17:57:00.395 27466-27501/com.example.a14 E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@a63cebe

This is the method used to buy an article. If it worked properly, method `Buy()` would be called when the user selected an article, and with variables for score, unlocked articles and activated articles, all operations would be done. This is the code for the `Buy()` method:

```
    public void Buy(View view) {

    //Database conection
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administration", null, 3);
    SQLiteDatabase Database= admin.getWritableDatabase();

    //Database query
    Cursor row = Database.rawQuery("select * from saved_data ", null);
    Cursor row2 = Database.rawQuery("select * from unlocked_articles", null);
    Cursor row3 = Database.rawQuery("select * from activated_articles", null);

    ContentValues record = new ContentValues();

    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);

    if (row.moveToFirst()) { //If db is not empty...

        int score = row.getInt(2);

        if(row2.moveToFirst()){

            int art0_unlock = row2.getInt(0); //One variable, one article
            int art1_unlock = row2.getInt(1);
            int art2_unlock = row2.getInt(2);
            int art3_unlock = row2.getInt(3);
            int art4_unlock = row2.getInt(4);

            if(row3.moveToFirst()){

                int art0_activ = row3.getInt(0); 
                int art1_activ = row3.getInt(1);
                int art2_activ = row3.getInt(2);
                int art3_activ = row3.getInt(3);
                int art4_activ = row3.getInt(4);

                if (art0.isSelected()) { ... } //Operations for the purchase are here, not the problem

                //For saving data

                record.put("score", score);

                record.put("art0_unlock", art0_unlock);
                record.put("art1_unlock", art1_unlock);
                record.put("art2_unlock", art2_unlock);
                record.put("art3_unlock", art3_unlock);
                record.put("art4_unlock", art4_unlock);

                record.put("art0_activ", art0_activ);
                record.put("art1_activ", art1_activ);
                record.put("art2_activ", art2_activ);
                record.put("art3_activ", art3_activ);
                record.put("art4_activ", art4_activ);

                Database.update("saved_data", record, null, null);
                Database.update("unlocked_articles", record, null, null);
                Database.update("activated_articles", record, null, null);

                tv_score.setText(score);

                row.close();
                row2.close();
                row3.close();


            }else{ //If activated_articles is empty...

                record.put("art0_activ", 0);
                record.put("art1_activ", 0);
                record.put("art2_activ", 0);
                record.put("art3_activ", 0);
                record.put("art4_activ", 0);

                Database.insert("activated_articles", null, record);

                row3.close();

            }

        }else{ //If unlocked_articles is empty...

            record.put("art0_unlock", 0);
            record.put("art1_unlock", 0);
            record.put("art2_unlock", 0);
            record.put("art3_unlock", 0);
            record.put("art4_unlock", 0);

            Database.insert("unlocked_articles", null, record);

            row2.close();

        }

        Database.close();

    }

}
```

And this is my AdminSQLiteOpenHelper code, is worth knowing that `unlocked_articles` and `activated_articles` where added later, that´s why I called `onUpgrade` method:

```
    package com.example.a14;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase Database) {

    Database.execSQL("create table saved_data(victories int, lvls_unlocked int, score int)");

    Database.execSQL("create table unlocked_articles(art0_unlock int, art1_unlock int, art2_unlock int, art3_unlock int, art4_unlock int)");

    Database.execSQL("create table activated_articles(art0_activ int, art1_activ int, art2_activ int, art3_activ int, art4_activ int)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase Database, int i, int i1) {

    Database.execSQL("create table unlocked_articles(art0_unlock int, art1_unlock int, art2_unlock int, art3_unlock int, art4_unlock int)");

    Database.execSQL("create table activated_articles(art0_activ int, art1_activ int, art2_activ int, art3_activ int, art4_activ int)");

    onCreate(Database);

}
```

}

I don´t know why this makes the app crash, as I don´t find errors. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have is that you are trying, if/when you get that far, to update columns that don't exist.

That is you have a single ContentValues (i.e. **record**) that you build that has columns from all 3 tables and then you are using this for the updates of all 3 tables. You will get a column not found SQLiteException like :-

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: art2_activ (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE saved_data SET art2_activ=?,score=?,art3_unlock=?,art4_unlock=?,art2_unlock=?,art3_activ=?,art1_activ=?,art0_unlock=?,art1_unlock=?,art4_activ=?,art0_activ=?
```

That is it cannot find the column **art2_activ** in the **saved_data** table (the column belongs to the activated_articles table).

As such you need 3 separate ContentValues, each appropriate to the respective table. I would also suggest closing the Cursors at the end irrespective of the path followed.

Here's a working example of that invokes your `Buy` method (twice first before adding some data and then after adding some data) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper db = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administration",null,3);
        Buy(); // test empty (if first run since install)
        
        /* NOTE insert methods added to the DB Helper to allow testing with some data */
        db.insertSaved(10,1,0);
        db.insertUnlocked(1,1,1,1,1);
        db.insertActivated(1,1,1,1,1);
        Buy(); // test with some data
    }
    public void Buy(/*View view <<<<<< COMMENTED OUT*/ ) {
        //Database conection
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administration", null, 3);
        SQLiteDatabase Database= admin.getWritableDatabase();

        //Database query
        Cursor row = Database.rawQuery("select * from saved_data ", null);
        Cursor row2 = Database.rawQuery("select * from unlocked_articles", null);
        Cursor row3 = Database.rawQuery("select * from activated_articles", null);
        ContentValues cv_score = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues cv_unlock = new ContentValues();
        ContentValues cv_activ = new ContentValues();

        //final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale); <<<<< COMMENTED OUT
        if (row.moveToFirst()) { //If db is not empty...
            int score = row.getInt(2);
            if(row2.moveToFirst()){
                int art0_unlock = row2.getInt(0); //One variable, one article
                int art1_unlock = row2.getInt(1);
                int art2_unlock = row2.getInt(2);
                int art3_unlock = row2.getInt(3);
                int art4_unlock = row2.getInt(4);

                if(row3.moveToFirst()){
                    int art0_activ = row3.getInt(0);
                    int art1_activ = row3.getInt(1);
                    int art2_activ = row3.getInt(2);
                    int art3_activ = row3.getInt(3);
                    int art4_activ = row3.getInt(4);
                    //if (art0.isSelected()) { ... } //Operations for the purchase are here, not the problem <<<<< COMMENTED OUT

                    //For saving data
                    cv_score.put("score",score);
                    cv_unlock.put("art0_unlock", art0_unlock);
                    cv_unlock.put("art1_unlock", art1_unlock);
                    cv_unlock.put("art2_unlock", art2_unlock);
                    cv_unlock.put("art3_unlock", art3_unlock);
                    cv_unlock.put("art4_unlock", art4_unlock);
                    cv_activ.put("art0_activ", art0_activ);
                    cv_activ.put("art1_activ", art1_activ);
                    cv_activ.put("art2_activ", art2_activ);
                    cv_activ.put("art3_activ", art3_activ);
                    cv_activ.put("art4_activ", art4_activ);
                    Database.update("saved_data", cv_score, null, null);
                    Database.update("unlocked_articles", cv_unlock, null, null);
                    Database.update("activated_articles", cv_activ, null, null);

                }else{ //If activated_articles is empty...
                    cv_activ.put("art0_activ", 0);
                    cv_activ.put("art1_activ", 0);
                    cv_activ.put("art2_activ", 0);
                    cv_activ.put("art3_activ", 0);
                    cv_activ.put("art4_activ", 0);
                    Database.insert("activated_articles", null, cv_activ);
                }

            }else{ //If unlocked_articles is empty...
                cv_unlock.put("art0_unlock", 0);
                cv_unlock.put("art1_unlock", 0);
                cv_unlock.put("art2_unlock", 0);
                cv_unlock.put("art3_unlock", 0);
                cv_unlock.put("art4_unlock", 0);
                Database.insert("unlocked_articles", null, cv_unlock);
            }
        }
        row.close();
        row2.close();
        row3.close();
        Database.close();
    }
}
```

- **Note** some code has been commented out
- instead of the single ContentValues **record** 3 ContentValues have been used **cv_score**, **cv_unlock** and **cv_activ**.

Comment: I implemented the changes that you suggested, but the logcat gave me the same errors.